# Arduino MKR1000 problem with only two HTTP Client Post Request

Tags: arduino-uno

When I use MKR1000 with ARDUINOHTTPCLIENT library and some simple http post example I have problem that my Arduino sends the request only twice. After that I get error code in response -2. I have tried to change time and restart the Arduino many times, but I keep getting the same problem. I change server domain where my Arduino make call and the problem is still same.

Here is code. Can anyone help me:

```
#include "ArduinoHttpClient.h"
#include "WiFi101.h"

//Setup Wifi Parameters
char ssid[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";    
char pass[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
char serverAddress[] = "xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com"; 
int port = 80;

WiFiClient wifi;
HttpClient client = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
String response;
int statusCode = 0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);                   

    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(6000);
  }

  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("making POST request");
  String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  String postData = "name=Alice&age=12";

  client.post("/public/insert_mysql.php HTTP/1.1", contentType, postData);

  // read the status code and body of the response
  statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  response = client.responseBody();

  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);

  Serial.println("Wait five seconds");
  delay(5000);
}
```

This is information from Serial Debug:

```
SSID: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
IP Address: xxxxxxxxx
making POST request
Status code: 200
Response: 
Wait five seconds
making POST request
Status code: 200
Response: 
Wait five seconds
making POST request
Status code: -2
Response: 
Wait five seconds
making POST request
Status code: -2
Response: 
Wait five seconds
making POST request
Status code: -2
Response: 
Wait five seconds
making POST request
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue...no answers. Pretty disappointed by the poor arduino examples and lack of community support